# Instantiate class from name in MATLAB

Tags: oop, class, matlab, dynamic, instantiation

I'm trying to list classes I created in some folder in my Matlab folder - using only their name (class name)

as an example, I have a class called 'SimpleString' - and I'm aiming to instantiate an object from that class, if all I know is that its name is 'SimpleString'

So in realtime, I'd like to find out what classes are in a folder (done), then be able to instantiate any of those classes (my question)
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html) to instantiate the class using just the class name.

```
instance = eval('SimpleString');
```

However, if you're simply iterating through all the m-files in a folder containing class definitions and grabbing the file names, you'll only be able to invoke the default constructor using this method.

Comment: This worked well for my goals - I already had all the "discovery" and metadata covered. I just needed to instantiate. Thanks!

Comment: `eval` can be used to execute arbitrary MATALB code, someone could quite easily slip in `eval('delete(''*.m'')')` and delete all your code files. `feval` is safer to use although one could do `feval('delete', '*.m')`, it's slightly harder to do.

Comment: @Sam Right, because *slightly harder* is enough to keep people from doing something malicious :) Amro's answer is better than mine, not sure why the OP didn't select that one.

Answer (score 12):

Use a **package**  to access class constructors with `.()`-notation.

A [Matlab package](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html) is simply a folder/directory with a name that begins with `+`:

#### +mypackage/foo.m:

```
classdef foo
    methods
        function obj = foo(arg1, arg2)
            %foo constructor
        end
    end
end
```

With class `foo` defined this way, you can access the constructor of `mypackage.foo` as

```
class_name = 'foo';
o = mypackage.(class_name)('arg1_value', 'arg2_value');
```

Comment: This seems to be a much better option than using `eval`.

Answer (score 10):

Use `str2func` to get a function handle to the constructor. You can then call it with whatever arguments are appropriate.

```
>> m = str2func('containers.Map')
m = 
    @containers.Map
>> x = m({'foo', 'bar'}, {0, 1})
x = 
  containers.Map handle
  Package: containers

  Properties:
        Count: 2
      KeyType: 'char'
    ValueType: 'double'
  Methods, Events, Superclasses
```

Comment: nice, concise. if anyone has a good reason not to use this for simple cases, I'd be interested to hear it.

Comment: don't combine this with user-input. In general not an issue within MATLAB, but something to keep in mind anyways. security is a programmers best friend! But 100% better than the currently selected correct answer

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [WHAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/what.html) function to discover classes (as well as functions,packages,etc...) in a certain folder, then call [METHODS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/methods.html) to find the signature of the constructor of the class (some parsing needed here), finally using [FEVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/feval.html) (passing arguments if any) to create an object from this class.

You could also use [meta.class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/meta.class.html) to get all sorts of meta-information about your classes.

---

## EDIT

Here is some code to illustrate what I had in mind:

```
%# folder containing your classes
pathName = fullfile(pwd,'folder');

%# make sure it is on the path
p = textscan(path, '%s', 'Delimiter',';'); p=p{1};
if ~any(ismember(p,pathName))
    addpath(pathName)
end

%# list MATLAB files
w = what(pathName);

%# get class names
fNames = cellfun(@(s) s(1:end-2), w.m, 'Uni',false);     %# remove .m extension
fNames = [fNames ; w.classes];        %# add classes in @-folders

%# get classes metadata
mt = cellfun(@meta.class.fromName, fNames, 'Uni',false); %# get meta-data
mt = mt( ~cellfun(@isempty,mt) );     %# get rid of plain functions

%# build object from each class
objects = cell(numel(mt),1);
for i=1:numel(mt)
    %# get contructor function
    ctorMT = findobj(mt{i}.MethodList, 'Access','public', 'Name',mt{i}.Name);

    %# get number of contructor arguments
    numArgs = numel(ctorMT.InputNames);

    %# create list of arguments (using just zeros)
    args = repmat({0}, [numArgs 1]);

    %# create object
    try
        obj = feval(ctorMT.Name,args{:});
    catch ME
        warning(ME.identifier, ME.message)
        obj = [];
    end

    %# store object
    objects{i} = obj;
end
```

As you can see, I found it easier to simply use `meta.class` to get metadata about the classes, instead of manually parsing the output of `methods('fcn','-full')` as I originally suggested.

However this is not perfect, as there is no way to find out what type of input each constructor expect (only how many). I opted to always pass `0` for each argument..

To test the implementation above, I create these sample classes (one in a self-contained file, the other defined in @-folder with multiple files):

#### folder/hello.m

```
classdef hello
    properties
        name = '';
    end
    methods
        function this = hello()
            this.name = 'world';
        end
        function val = get.name(obj)
            val = obj.name;
        end
        function obj = set.name(obj,val)
            obj.name = val;
        end
        function say(obj)
            fprintf('Hello %s!\n',obj.name);
        end
    end
end
```

#### folder/@hello2/hello2.m

```
classdef hello2
    properties
        name
    end
    methods
        function this = hello2(val)
            this.name = val;
        end
        function val = get.name(obj)
            val = obj.name;
        end
        function obj = set.name(obj,val)
            obj.name = val;
        end
    end
    methods
        say(obj)
    end
end
```

#### folder/@hello2/say.m

```
function say(obj)
    fprintf('Hello2 %s!\n', obj.name);
end
```

Comment: finding the constructor the way you are doing will fail for any class within a package, the Name property of the metaclass will be package.classname while the functions Name property will just be classname