# How to get the handle of a method in an Object (class inst) within MATLAB

Tags: oop, class, matlab, methods

I'm trying to grab a method handle from within an object in MATLAB, yet something in the sort of str2func('obj.MethodName') is not working

Comment: I now realize that I might have skipped an important part of the question: 
My goal is to take a function name through a string (char array), and run it (for autodetection of available functions within a class for instance) - 

This seems to work generally, but specifically within classes, running feval with ['obj.' functionName], where functionName is some char array, does not resolve.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you considered using [meta-information](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/br4iuh2.html) of classes/objects. I did post an example in a previous question of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102828/instantiate-class-from-name-in-matlab/7107012#7107012

Answer (score 6):

The answer is to get a function handle as [@Pablo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628343/how-to-get-the-handle-of-a-method-in-an-object-class-inst-within-matlab/7628436#7628436) has shown.

Note that your class should be derived from the `handle` class for this to work correctly (so that the object is passed by reference).

Consider the following example:

#### Hello.m

```
classdef hello < handle
    properties
        name = '';
    end
    methods
        function this = hello()
            this.name = 'world';
        end
        function say(this)
            fprintf('Hello %s!\n', this.name);
        end
    end
end
```

Now we get a handle to the member function, and use it:

```
obj = hello();         %# create object
f = @obj.say;          %# get handle to function

obj.name = 'there';    %# change object state

obj.say()
f()
```

The output:

```
Hello there!
Hello there!
```

However if we define it as a [Value Class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brfylq3.html) instead (change first line to `classdef hello`), the output would be different:

```
Hello there!
Hello world!
```

Answer (score 6):

One could also write

```
fstr = 'say';
obj.(fstr)();
```

This has the advantage that it does not require a handle class to work if the object (obj) is modified.

Answer (score 5):

Use `@`. The following code works for me:

```
f = @obj.MethodName
```

Answer (score 1):

No other answer mimics `str2func('obj.MethodName')`. Actually, this one doesn't either, not exactly. But you can define an auxillary function like so:

```
function handle = method_handle(obj, mstr)
    handle = @(varargin) obj.(mstr)(varargin{:});
end
```

Then `method_handle(obj, 'MethodName')` returns a handle to `obj.MethodName`. Unfortunately, you cannot pass the variable name of `obj` as a string - `eval("obj")` will be undefined in the function's scope.