# Matlab "class handles"?

Tags: matlab

I'd like to iterate over Matlab classes.  Is this possible?

My application has several subclasses based on different structures and algorithms, but each subclass implements the same (class and instance) methods. So it is natural for me to have test-cases which have the subclass as a parameter.  In Ruby, for example, this is would be easy

```
[ClassA, ClassB].each do |cls|
  if cls.some_class_method? then
    instance = cls.new
    :
  end
end
```

but I don't seem to be able to find a way to do this in Matlab, there don't seem to be "class handles".

Is there a way?

[edit]

Following @zeeMonkeez's solution I ended up with the following

```
function varargout = call_method(class_name, method_name, varargin)
  qualified_name = sprintf('%s.%s', class_name, method_name);
  [varargout{1:nargout}] = feval(qualified_name, varargin{:});
end
```

which I can call in my test-case like

```
class_name = 'MVPolyCube';
  :
[x, y, z] = call_method(class_name, 'variables');
```

which solves my problem and DRYs up my test suite.  Thanks all!

Comment: Can you provide an explanation that makes sense and isn't in Ruby?

Comment: I'd like to have a variable which holds the class, and to be able to call methods from the variable rather than the class.  So `cls = ClassA` assigns class `ClassA` to the variable `cls`, then call `cls.new` to create a new instance of `ClassA` ..., none of this works in Matlab of course.  I ask if there is an equivalent way that this can be done in Matlab.

Comment: Like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sco1/b2d47cd43257d15cc77836193b27a448) and `cls = testcode; instance = cls.new;`?

Comment: Does [this discussion](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/322671) help? Basically, the recommendation is to have a factory function.

Comment: @excaza, yes, and I'd like to do `for cls = [testcode1, testcode2] ; ...`

Comment: @zeeMonkeez, thanks, I have tried a similar approach; but it would mean that I'd need to have a factory for each "class method", something I'd hoped to avoid

Comment: Another option is given in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20146447/1893154), showing how to access class names dynamically if they are in a package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using `feval`, you could do something like the code below.
Basically, we test if a static method of a given name exists for a class name (using [`meta.class`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meta.class.html)). Then we get the return value of said method using [`feval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feval.html?searchHighlight=feval). Based on that, we instantiate an object or not (again using `feval`).

`A.m`:

```
classdef A
    methods
        function whoami(this)
            fprintf('I am an A\n');
        end
    end
    methods(Static)
        function out = a
            out = true;
            fprintf('A.a returns %i\n', out);
        end
    end
end
```

`B.m`:

```
classdef B
    methods
        function whoami(this)
            fprintf('I am a B\n');
        end
    end
    methods(Static)
        function out = a
            out = false;
            fprintf('B.a returns %i\n', out);
        end
        function out = b
            out = true;
            fprintf('B.b returns %i\n', out);
        end
    end
end
```

`has_static_method.m`, will be used to test if a class has a static function:

```
function res = has_static_method(class_name, method_name) 
    mc = meta.class.fromName(class_name);
    ml = mc.MethodList;
    ml = ml([mc.MethodList.Static]);
    res = any(strcmp(method_name, {ml.Name}));
end
```

`test.m`:

```
classes = {'A', 'B'};
for i_c = 1:numel(classes)
    klass_name = classes{i_c};
    static_function_name = 'a';
    if has_static_method(klass_name, static_function_name) && feval(sprintf('%s.%s', klass_name, static_function_name))
        an_object = feval(klass_name);
        an_object.whoami
    end
    static_function_name = 'b';
    if has_static_method(klass_name, static_function_name) && feval(sprintf('%s.%s', klass_name, static_function_name))
        an_object = feval(klass_name);
        an_object.whoami
    end
end
```

Comment: A not so clean way is to use try/catch instead of searching for methods.

Comment: @Navan Haven't properly thought this through, but it seems like `try`/`catch` wouldn't be a great idea here, because what if `klass_name` is a struct variable with a field `static_function_name`? That might lead to unintended consequences...

Comment: Agreed, try/catch would need to make an assumption that the error is only because of missing method on a class.